# Getting Android activity reference in unity 3d

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

[See this link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahGeTNUPLM)

Tried this one but it's not getting the reference of the activity

Comment: so we have watch whole video to know what you have  tried ?

Comment: What are the tools you are using... Do you have the Pro Version of Unity.

Comment: It's easier to spot and point out the issue if you show us some code instead

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet, from this [github repo](https://github.com/hkusoft/Use-Android-Inside-Unity/blob/master/Examples/Unity3D/UnityExamples/Assets/02InjectSimpleAndroidUI/InjectSimpleAndroidUI.cs):

```
public static AndroidJavaObject GetAndroidActivity()
{
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    return jo;
}
```